How can I break a horizontal line at a double vertical line in the tabular environment?
In the tabular environment, \hline \hline breaks vertical lines in the table. I want to create this behavior in the reverse direction: I want an \hline that breaks when it encounters a double vertical line in the table.
I am not currently using any packages relating to tabular behavior, but I am happy to use any that would help me with this.

hhline package but seriously consider not having vertical rules (see the booktabs package comments about vertical rules)

Could you add a minimal working example?

Thank you @DavidCarlisle! This package was very helpful, and I was able to solve my problem by looking at the examples in the documentation file.

hhline package provides \hhline specifically for this feature, but seriously consider not having vertical rules (see the booktabs package comments about vertical rules in tables found on pg 3).
